Why is GCC inserting a no-op "mov edi, edi" at the beginning of this function?
Given the simple function:
double uniform_double_from_int(unsigned n) {
    return n / 4294967296.0;
}

GCC 13.2 with -O3 generates the following assembly:
uniform_double_from_int(unsigned int):
        mov     edi, edi
        vxorps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vcvtsi2sd       xmm0, xmm0, rdi
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1039138816

Why on earth is GCC performing the no-op mov edi, edi at the begining of this function?

Does this answer your question? What is the purpose of 'mov edi, edi'? on reverseengineering.SE

@DevSolar: That question seems to be in the context of a 32-bit program, where mov edi, edi actually is a noop and is intended as such. Here we have a 64-bit program and it isn't a noop.

@NateEldredge I wasn't sure, which is why I posted it as a manual comment instead of a close vote. There had been a comment by the OP that the link didn't match his problem, which seems to be gone now. I left the link here in case others land on this Q looking for the other answer.
